# How to set up right bar button in nav bar from a tabbed view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Ok, so i'm trying to set up the rightbarbutton for my `UINavigationBar` and it doesn't want to show up.I am pushing my `UIViewController` using self.navigationController push method and when i do the following :

```
for (UIViewController *vc in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
    NSLog(@"VC : %@",NSStringFromClass(vc.class));
```

}

from the view controller i just pushed, the result is 2 tabbarcontrollers because the previous view controller from which i pushed is a tab out of 2 within a tabbarcontroller... is this related to the fact that my navigation bar right button isn't showing up?

simply doing :

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logout" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(performLogout:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btn;
```

doesn't do the trick

Comment: You're probably trying to add the button to the wrong object. You can try self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem or better debug find the right object.

Comment: Try this line     self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btn;

Comment: I've tried all of that...but as a new update i've also tried this UINavigationItem * item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"FB"];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:item];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setRightBarButtonItem:btn animated:YES];    and this apparently shows logout button for the previous view controller (the one from which i pushed)

Comment: The thing is that i can't seem to be able to make it work when i also have my pushed viewcontroller within a tab bar controller